# Get Lowest Offers for Entire Inventory on Amazon

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

We are just getting started with MWS. We'd like to be able to use the lowest offers on each product to help calculate our price. There is an API to GetLowestOfferListForSku but that only returns a single sku and there is a throttle limit which would make it so we'd have to take several days to get all the data.

Does anybody know a way to get that data for multiple products in a single request?

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch data on up to 20 SKUs using `GetLowestOfferListingsForSKU` by adding a `SellerSKUList.SellerSKU.n` parameter for each product (where `n` is a number from 1 to 20). The request looks something like this:

```
https://mws.amazonservices.com/Products/2011-10-01
?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJGUVGFGHNKE2NVUA
&Action=GetMatchingProduct
&SellerId=A2NK2PX936TF53
&SignatureVersion=2
&Timestamp=2012-02-07T01%3A22%3A39Z
&Version=2011-10-01
&Signature=MhSREjubAxTGSldGGWROxk4qvi3sawX1inVGF%2FepJOI%3D
&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256
&MarketplaceId=ATVPDKIKX0DER
&SellerSKUList.SellerSKU.1=SKU1
&SellerSKUList.SellerSKU.2=SKU2
&SellerSKUList.SellerSKU.3=SKU3
```

Here's some relevant documentation which explains this: http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/products/Products_ProcessingBulkOperationRequests.html

You might also find the MWS scratchpad helpful for testing:
https://mws.amazonservices.com/scratchpad/index.html